# Change "et al." to "and N other authors" or similar

Tags: bibtex

I'm compiling a bibliography in which some author lists are very long (100+). I know about the "et al." option for BibTeX styles but instead of

```
One, Two, Three, et al. (2016)
```

or similar, I'd rather have something like

```
One, Two, Three, and 97 other authors (2016)
```

for a paper with 100 authors.

I've used `latex makebst` to create a custom bibliography style and I can just about see that the number of remaining authors for the "et al." is known to BibTeX (in `format.names` in my custom `bst`). But I'm not nearly knowledgeable enough about BibTeX to know how to get this into the citation.

Is there a way to get the desired output?

PS: Apologies if this is a duplicate but I could only turn up a lot of questions and answers for putting "et al." in the references.

Comment: Do you want to indicate which papers have to be mentioned in this format, or should this automatically be the case if the total number of authors supersedes a given number?

Comment: I was hoping it could be done automatically, whenever BibTeX detects a long author list (that would normally be partially replaced with "et al.").

Comment: Where I can download your `.bst` file ?

Comment: Does [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv718fwc7bxmfwv/example.bst?dl=0) work? The function `format.names` starts at line 416 and seems to have a variable `namesleft`. But I might be misinterpreting the code. I almost never look at `bst` source.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got something that works but I'll wait to see if there are any other answers first. In short, I found where the "et al." is added, then subtracted the number of printed names from the `numnames` variable (which is the total number of authors) and wrote that in the place of "et al.". So where I had `" " * bbl.etal *` on line 452 I now have `" and " * numnames #15 - int.to.str$ * " others" *`. Seems to work...

Comment: The meaning of `nameptr #1  #15 + = numnames #0 #30 +`:  it must show only 15 author names if the number of authors is more than 30. So, in your case you must replace `#15` by `#3`

Comment: Do you want to show only the authors and the year, or you want to modify only the names?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you define a number which is the number of authors you want to show, to do this add to `ENTRY {` in your `.bst` file `nbr` so it will become:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    eid
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
    nbr % added
  }
```

then search for `FUNCTION {format.names}` and replace it by

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      highlight.if.cv.author
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #1
          #3 + = %#15 + =     
          numnames #0
          #10 + %#30 +
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              " " *  
              t "others" =
                {
                  * "and " * nbr " other authors" *    
                }
                { ", " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```

and in your `bib` file add e.g `nbr = {33}` to have something like `Author 1, Author 2, Author 3 and 33 other authors`

N.B: This will show only 3 authors name (if the number of authors is superior than 10) followed by `and nbr other authors`, where `nbr` must be added to the BiTeX Entry in the same way you add the `pages` , `journal` ... etc . To change this just replace `#3` and `#10` by the number you want.

**Update:** As **Warrick** suggest you do not need to add `nbr` but instead just replace `nbr` in the above `format.names` with `numnames #3 - int.to.str$`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
   \begin{filecontents*}{MWE.bib}
     @article{A,
      archivePrefix = {arXiv},
      arxivId = {hep-th/9605032},
      author = {AuthorI, A. and AuthorII, B. and AuthorIII, C.},
      eprint = {9605032},
      journal = {Journal of Bla bla},
      pages = {12},
      primaryClass = {hep-th},
      title = {{Title of the paper A}},
      volume = {123},
      year = {2016}
        }
     @article{B,
      archivePrefix = {arXiv},      
      author = {Author1, A and Author2, A and Author3, A and Author4, A and Author5, A and Author6, A
                 and Author6, A and Author7, A and Author8, A and Author9, Aand Author10, A and Author11, A
                 and Author12, A
                 },
      arxivId = {1512.00704},
      eprint = {1512.00704},
      journal = {Journal of bla bla},
      pages = {1233},
      title = {{Title of the paper B}},
      volume = {567},
      year = {2016},
      nbr = {9}
        }
     @article{C,
      archivePrefix = {arXiv},      
      author = {Author1, A and Author2, A and Author3, A and Author4, A and Author5, A and Author6, A
                 and Author6, A and Author7, A and Author8, A and Author9
                 },
      arxivId = {1512.00704},
      eprint = {1512.00704},
      journal = {Journal of bla bla},
      pages = {1233},
      title = {{Title of the paper B}},
      volume = {567},
      year = {2016}
        }   
  \end{filecontents*}
  \begin{document}

   ~\nocite{*}

 %Bibleography

 \bibliographystyle{example}
 \bibliography{MWE}
 \end{document}
```

Which gives:
[image]

Comment: This is very close to the desired behaviour, except that I'm pretty sure it can be done without creating the new variable `nbr`. In your example, if I replace `nbr` in your `format.names` with `numnames #3 - int.to.str$`, I think it automatically calculates the number of missing authors. Obviously the 3 is the hardcoded number for how many names are printed, which can be changed as you suggest.

Comment: You're right !.

Comment: @Warrick feel free to edit the answer

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution using `biblatex`:

All one has to do is to define a new directive to format names:

```
\newcounter{namesleft}
\DeclareNameFormat{andNothers}{%
  \setcounter{namesleft}{\value{author}-\value{liststop}}%
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \namepartfamily
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\addspace}%
    {\ifmorenames{\printtext{ and other \thenamesleft{} authors}}{}}
}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{andNothers}
```

In the snippet above first we create a new counter (`names left`) to store the number of names left to process. Such number is obtained from the difference of the number to be printed when a name is truncated (stored in the `minames` parameters to be given it the `biblatex` option and the total number of names in the list stored by the counter (`author` in this case).  When we each the last name to be printed, we use the `\ifmorenames` conditional to check whether the list is going to be truncated; if so, it prints the value of `namesleft`.

Finally, we use `\DeclareNameAlias` to specify that we use the new format to print the list of authors.

The solution uses the `calc` package to simplify the computation  of the counters, and the parameters of how many names are required before truncating the list and how many names are included when truncated are the standard `maxnames` and `minnames`. Thus,

```
\usepackage[minnames=3,maxnames=5]{biblatex}
```

specifies truncate name list if more that 5 names are present, but display only the first 3 names.

Here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
     @article{A,
      archivePrefix = {arXiv},
      arxivId = {hep-th/9605032},
      author = {AuthorI, A. and AuthorII, B. and AuthorIII, C.},
      eprint = {9605032},
      journal = {Journal of Bla bla},
      pages = {12},
      primaryClass = {hep-th},
      title = {{Title of the paper A}},
      volume = {123},
      year = {2016}
        }
     @article{B,
      archivePrefix = {arXiv},      
      author = {Author1, A and Author2, A and Author3, A and Author4, A and Author5, A and Author6, A
                 and Author6, A and Author7, A and Author8, A and Author9, Aand Author10, A and Author11, A
                 and Author12, A
                 },
      arxivId = {1512.00704},
      eprint = {1512.00704},
      journal = {Journal of bla bla},
      pages = {1233},
      title = {{Title of the paper B}},
      volume = {567},
      year = {2016},
      nbr = {9}
        }
     @article{C,
      archivePrefix = {arXiv},      
      author = {Author1, A and Author2, A and Author3, A and Author4, A and Author5, A and Author6, A
                 and Author6, A and Author7, A and Author8, A and Author9
                 },
      arxivId = {1512.00704},
      eprint = {1512.00704},
      journal = {Journal of bla bla},
      pages = {1233},
      title = {{Title of the paper C}},
      volume = {567},
      year = {2016}
        }   
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[minnames=3,maxnames=5]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcounter{namesleft}
\DeclareNameFormat{andNothers}{%
  \setcounter{namesleft}{\value{author}-\value{liststop}}%
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \namepartfamily
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\addspace}%
    {\ifmorenames{\printtext{ and other \thenamesleft{} authors}}{}}
}


\DeclareNameAlias{author}{andNothers}

\begin{document}


\nocite{*}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution to the problem. I modified/tweaked the Chicago style (Chicago.sty) and I replace "et al." with "and others" in the bibliography style (ChicagoFred.bst); below an example; it includes a .tex as an example.

[github file](https://github.com/FreddyRedBed/biblatex/tree/master/Template)

The reason I modified some lines in the Chicago style is because there was an issue with parentheses (if you use a colorful hyperlink, then you have a colorless parenthesis). I fixed it.

Comment: I would not change anything in `chicago.sty`. Better is add patch to it in your document preamble.

Comment: Interesting reply. Could you do that? please free to take the files and do it. Thanks.